# Dynamically make an interface. c#

Tags: c#, templates, dictionary, dynamic, interface

Is it possible to dynamically make an interface in C#, (maybe by using reflection?).

I want to create this interface based on a dictionary with keys and values. Each key would be a field or a property of the newly made interface. There are potentially hundreds of dictionaries like these and I'm trying to find a way to do this dynamically, doesn't matter if there are hundreds of `ICustomInterfaceSomeName.cs` files generated.

I checked [this link about T4 text templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee844259.aspx) but I can't figure out how to apply it to my issue. I also checked this [link](http://philsversion.com/2009/08/12/dynamically-generating-an-interface-implementation-at-runtime/) but it doesn't really apply to what I am trying to achieve. I see a lot of questions about how to *implement* an interface dynamically but not how to *create* it from scratch with some data.

Can someone point me in the right direction or give me some pointers?

**Intended usage:**

What I'm trying to do is getting a final object that implements the said interfaces to have intellisense with the dictionaries. This is related to this [**question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31181465/make-new-object-with-reflection). The point is making objects dynamically that can implement these interfaces in order to have intellisense while writing code.

I am guessing this would require to build the unfinished code for the interfaces to be generated and then have intellisense.

*If the question is a duplicate or isn't clear, don't hesitate to comment so I can remedy it*

Comment: Can you give an example of the intended usage? I can't understand why you would be trying to do this.

Comment: @PMF I edited it with some clarification.

Comment: What about this answer?
http://stackoverflow.com/a/1822338/266978

What you need, in general, is reflection: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.aspx

Comment: @Baltasarq from what I see, I would need the interface beforehand, and that is exactly the problem. Except if I can make an interface using reflection? Maybe I missed something?

Comment: "Each key would be a field or a property of the newly made interface". What do the values represent? What type are the keys, or does it vary?

Comment: Since there are hundreds of these dictionaries, how discoverable are they? Are they public and static, all in one assembly, meaning they could be found by reflection?

Comment: @DavidArno All the values are strings and all keys are strings as well. The dictionaries can be easily discoverable, they are the return parameter from another method, a method that is public. So I think they can be found by reflection.

Comment: @Joze, I haven't dug deep, but I suppose you can create an interface the same way you create a class. The key method seems to be DefineType() (5th line in the example above), which basically accepts a name and a collection of TypeAttributes. One of the TypeAttributes is indeed Interface, so DefineType( "MyIntf", TypeAttribute.Interface ) should work.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.typeattributes(v=vs.71).aspx